# UIPageViewController : move programmatically page doesn't work

Tags: swift, button, move, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I try to turn the page by touching a button on one of the two navigation controllers(each navigationcontroller is related to a viewcontroller) but when i call a function in the pageviewcontroller to change index and change page it doesn't work at all...

I tried setViewController.

I would like to do like in the snapchat app, a navbuttonitem which can slide to the left or to the right.

Thank you in advance

here is the code of the pageviewcontroller :

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{

    var index = 0
    var identifiers: NSArray = ["FirstNavigationController", "SecondNavigationController"]

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self

    let startingViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(self.index)
    let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]
    self.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil) 
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UINavigationController! {

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    //first view controller = firstViewControllers navigation controller
    if index == 0 {

        return storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstNavigationController") as UINavigationController

    }

    //second view controller = secondViewController's navigation controller
    if index == 1 {

        return storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondNavigationController") as UINavigationController
    }

    return nil
}
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier
    let index = self.identifiers.indexOfObject(identifier!)

    //if the index is the end of the array, return nil since we dont want a view controller after the last one
    if index == identifiers.count - 1 {

        return nil
    }

    //increment the index to get the viewController after the current index
    self.index = self.index + 1
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(self.index)

}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier
    let index = self.identifiers.indexOfObject(identifier!)

    //if the index is 0, return nil since we dont want a view controller before the first one
    if index == 0 {

        return nil
    }

    //decrement the index to get the viewController before the current one
    self.index = self.index - 1
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(self.index)

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why don't you stop each instance of your controllers rather than re-instantiating it ? Here is the line :

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UINavigationController! {

let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
//first view controller = firstViewControllers navigation controller
if index == 0 {

    return storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstNavigationController") as UINavigationController

}

//second view controller = secondViewController's navigation controller
if index == 1 {

    return storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondNavigationController") as UINavigationController
}

return nil}
```

You could create a local array containing all your instances..

Then, to move programmatically between your pages, you can use `setViewController` this way :

```
func showAViewController(){
    let startVC : NSArray = [viewController]

    setViewControllers(startVC as! [AnyObject], direction: .Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Where direction is .Reverse or .Forward depending on the position of the destination view controller relative to the present view controller.

Here is an example of a test program I wrote, it worked for me :

```
class RootVC: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var viewController1 : UIViewController!
var viewController2 : UIViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource = self

    viewController1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController1") as! UIViewController
    viewController1.title = "viewController1"

    viewController2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController2") as! UIViewController
    viewController2.title = "viewController2"

    var startingVC : NSArray = [viewController1]
    setViewControllers(startingVC as! [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    Notifications.addObserver(self, selector: "showViewController1", name: "showViewController1", object: nil)
    Notifications.addObserver(self, selector: "showViewController2", name: "showViewController2", object: nil)
}

deinit{
    Notifications.removeObserver(self)
}

func showViewController1(){
    let startVC : NSArray = [viewController1]

    setViewControllers(startVC as! [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func showViewController2(){
    let startVC : NSArray = [viewController1]

    setViewControllers(startVC as! [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    switch viewController.title!{
        case "viewController1": return nil
        case "viewController2": return viewController1
    default: return nil
    }
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    switch viewController.title!{
    case "viewController1": return viewController2
    case "viewController2": return viewController1
    default: return nil
    }
}}
```

`NSNotifications`is not a mandatory, but I like to use it to avoid heavy delegation.